Script randomly stopped working, despite not changing it or updating g hub
I've tried restarting, and it used to work. Now it does nothing and am unsure what else to do, it just keeps saying the final like 'end' is a syntax error, and explains nothing else in the consosle if you know please help.
--------------------------------------
---------- Dont touch this -----------
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents  (true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
if EnableRCS ~= false then
if RequireToggle ~= false then
    if IsKeyLockOn(ToggleKey)then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,RecoilControlStrength)
                        Sleep(DelayRate)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
    
else 

        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,RecoilControlStrength)
                        Sleep(DelayRate)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
else 
end  
end


This script is not full, so it can not work at all.  Not defined variables and functions: RecoilControlStrength, DelayRate, MoveMouseRelative, ToggleKey

it just keeps saying the final like 'end' is a syntax error - The script you posted is syntactically correct, it can not raise this error.

else 
end 

The else is the problem. There is no other code before the end at the else. As advice, next time align the code properly and format it to see matching begin-of-statements with their end and you'll find the problems a lot faster. This is the easiest way.

thank you, how would i fix this if you dont mind helping?{ im still new to coding

Delete else before the last end. Just make a backup before. You most likely changed it and forgot because it is impossible for it to have worked like this before. Or you copy pasted part of it or deleted the else block. The golden rule is always backup. Then do a recursive "Read Only" setting on the all of the child files and directories inside backup. (you might accidentally keep the backup open and accidentally edit it - yes, that happened to me when I first started).
